# How to draw a squiggly in Photoshop?

Tags: shapes, pen-tool, image-trace

I'm trying to draw a squigly line exactly like the one in the picture to be used as in illustration featuring Styrofoam peanuts.

I've tried the pen tool (with my amateurish skills) and I've even tried using an `S` from a cool font but it wasn't quite right.

Is there a way to do this well with the pen tool, or another technique someone can suggest?

[image: Squigly from Game of Set]

Comment: Illustrator would be better for this.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have Photoshop

Comment: Sorry for my late reply @Imray but just to let you know, [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is an open source vector graphics software. Scott's answer below would apply as an apt tutorial for any of these programs including Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the **Pen Tool** to draw the outer shape. Then it's a simple matter to add a pattern overlay for the stripes and a stroke for the outer boundary.

[image]

The color overlay in this screenshot merely changes the color of my stripe pattern from black to red.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on quality of the image you can try selecting the blue or the reverse (white/negative space then Inverse the selection - CMD+SHIFT+I or CTRL+SHIFT+I or From the menu Select -> Inverse). After making the selection converting it with the ['Make work path from Selection'](https://imgur.com/XxeOvw3), from the path panel on the bottom.

Results may very, Your best option is to [Pen Tool](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html) it (practice makes perfect).